# Process.Start() with arguments to start Google Chrome

Tags: .net, shell, google-chrome, process, process.start

I am trying to launch Google Chrome browser from a .NET program, with arguments. But I get strange behavior.

The following launches Chrome in '*incognito*' mode from a command line. It works fine.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --incognito
```

But the following does not work in .NET. Chrome does open, but not incognito and it goes to this weird URL: `http://xn---incognito-nu6e/`

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "–-incognito")
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use shortcut when call the `chrome.exe` instead using full path location.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", "--incognito")
    End Sub
End Module
```

More: [start-google-chrome-from-run-windows-key-r](http://ayumilove.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/start-google-chrome-from-run-windows-key-r/)

**UPDATE**

I found what is your problem in your code.
Your code using `–-incognito` in the parameter, but it should be `--incognito`.

See the first character in that parameter. Should be `-` instead `–`.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "--incognito")
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: So, before I modified the registry as per the link you provided, I was able to use the short name "chrome.exe" in .NET, but the arguments were messed up. Now I have modifed the registry entry (by adding `%1` to the `Default` key), and now I am unable to use the short name "chrome.exe" because it is not found, but I have to use the full path. However the arguments work well now, like they are supposed to. So, why can't I use the short name now?

Comment: Those characters appear identical on my screen, both are 'minus' characters. Can you clarify?

Comment: `–` appear in my browser. :). I just copy your code. Try to copy my code

Comment: Wow, I had to look in a Hex editor to see the difference. I must have copied that mess from a web browser in the beginning and never changed it. It works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also read the chrome path from the registry:

```
    public static string GetChromePath()
    {
        string lPath = null;
        try
        {
            var lTmp = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe", "", null);
            if (lTmp != null)
                lPath = lTmp.ToString();
            else
            {
                lTmp = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe", "", null);
                if (lTmp != null)
                    lPath = lTmp.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception lEx)
        {
            Logger.Error(lEx);
        }

        if (lPath == null)
        {
            Logger.Warn("Chrome install path not found! Returning hardcoded path");
            lPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
        }

        return lPath;
    }
```