# WPF Chrome Incognito windows open

Tags: c#, wpf

When I clicked button, incognito window must be open but I can't write them.

I need help from incognito window.

Comment: Translation attempt: I require a button that will open a Chrome Incognito Window in C#. How can I achieve this? Also, I can't speak English very well. (Sorry)

Comment: İ don't understand your post Sorry.

Comment: @EmreŞahin Try Google Translate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Process.Start() with arguments to start Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396147/process-start-with-arguments-to-start-google-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Following should help you.

If you don't care about memory leak or other stuff then here is the one-liner

```
Process.Start(@"chrome.exe", "--incognito http://SomeURLToOpenInIncognitoMode");
```

or

Try an efficient and better way (no memory leaks), which is as follows

```
string url = "http://SomeURLToOpenInIncognitoMode";

using (var process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\chrome.exe"; //chrome installed path
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = url + " --incognito"; //incognito argument is the trick!

    process.Start();
}
```

Comment: In future, try not to encourage "Please give me code that does xyz..." posts.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul sure. sorry for helping :|

Comment: It's not considered helping

Comment: Yup, got it. I'll keep it in mind. Thanks for making me aware :)